# How to check whether my android app is successfully installable or not?

Tags: java, android, testing, automated-tests

I've a simple Android app on which I'm depending on n number of libraries by adding them to my `dependencies` list in my `Config` file. Sometimes the changes done in the dependent library causing my app to crash and making it non-installable (means it is producing some runtime crash due to bug in their code) and making my app uninstallable.

Is there a way to find it during build time by running a test suite on my app to find this breakage. It's really hard to manually test them each time for each and every minor release.

I'm quite new to Android space. So, I've no idea whether this is achievable or not. It would be helpful if someone could provide a pointer to this.

If you feel the question is too naive or stupid suggest me in comments to add more details on what.

Comment: you could try to install it..

Comment: *Sometimes the changes done in the dependent library causing my app to crash* - If you are using a specific version this shouldn't happen, as all changes require a new version. If the developer of this "dependent library" is overriding the same version again just change library.

Comment: You can use continuous integration? Like Microsoft's Visual Studio App Center?